# TypeError: pack_configure() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I keep getting this error TypeError: pack_configure() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'.
I don't know why since iv run the code and its worked before this is the code i'm trying to run

```
my_window = Tk()
my_canvas_1 = Canvas(my_window, height=500, width=500, bg='white')
my_canvas_2 = Canvas(my_window, height=500, width=250, bg='white')
my_canvas_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
my_canvas_2.grid(row=0, column=1)
Canvas.pack()
my_window.mainloop()
```

this should make 2 canvases using tkinter however as explained above it keeps displaying an error I think it has something to do with packing the canvas I am a little new to python so I might just be being dumb but if not please help

Comment: By the error type either TK class or Canvas class method are not defined well , can you share those class?

Comment: What are trying to do here `Canvas.pack()`? To me, you are calling a method of Canvas directly without creating an instance of the Canvas class.

Comment: `Canvas.pack()` is not necessary and should be removed.

Comment: @NirElbaz: Those classes are part of the `tkinter` module.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the line `Canvas.pack()`. That is calling `pack` on the `Canvas` class, but it needs to be called on an instance. Since you're already calling `grid` on the instances, this line is useless and needs to be removed.